# Stop AngularJS from caching html between routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two routes in a page wired up with Angular JS.

One page has a form from which you can save some information, angular seems to be not requesting for the html when I switch back and forth between the routes.

I have tried doing $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;

Basically for one route I don't want Angular to be caching the html, for the other routes it is actually a good thing.

Code is given here:

```
angular.module('userAccount', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
      //$httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
      $routeProvider
        .when('/UserProfile/:action', {
            reloadOnSearch: false,
            cache: false,
            templateUrl: function (params) {
                return '/UserProfile/' + params.action;
            },
            controller: 'UserProfCtrl'
        })
        .when('/UserDashboard/:action', {
            templateUrl: function (params) {
                return '/UserDashboard/' + params.action;
            },
            controller: 'UserDashCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise('/UserDashboard/Index');
  }])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location',
  function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
      $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (next, current) {

      });

      this.$route = $route;
      this.$location = $location;
      this.$routeParams = $routeParams;
  }])
.controller('UserProfCtrl', ['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
    this.name = "UserProfCtrl";
    this.params = $routeParams;
}])
.controller('UserDashCtrl', ['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
    this.name = "UserDashCtrl";
      this.params = $routeParams;
    }]);
```

Note that i have removed some unrelated ui manipulation code here.

Comment: if `cache: false` didn't work for you then please share your code

Comment: I have updated the question with code, the uncommented section is what i had tried. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have same problem in my hybrid mobile app and resolved by adding cache: false in my route.js

```
$stateProvider.state('stateName', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/url',
   templateUrl : 'template.html'
})
```

Hope it will resolve your problem as well.

you can try to add query string with url

```
return '/views/' + params.action+'?'+$.now();
```

Comment: I am not using a state provider, should I be? I have updated the question with code.

Comment: adding query string to url will avoid caching to your template

Comment: worked with the now thing, i had sent http headers to indicate to the browsers to not to cache before (which is what 'now' is solving), I guess that wasn't respected.

Comment: Does adding `cache:false, ` actually do anything? If not, why is it the biggest part of the answer?

Comment: $.now() prevent caching in browser

Answer (score 3):

I know its late but it may help someone

I just used this before my routes and it worked.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching in many sites, i haven't found a correct solution of this, but watching the question and the answer in this post, I have made the next solution than solved my problem (no at all).

If I clicked two consecutive times into the products' link, the second clic don't reload/evaluate the content, but if I clicked on other link and then click on the link produtcs, angular reload the content of this.

```
            var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

            app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

                $routeProvider
                .when("/", {
                    templateUrl : "main.php"
                })
                .when("/productos", {
                    disableCache: true,
                    templateUrl : function (params) {
                        return "productos.php?" + $.now();
                    }
                })
                .when("/contacto", {
                    templateUrl : "contacto.php"
                })

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            }]);
```